# Print result to every second line of output file in awk

Tags: bash, awk

Seems no one yet stumbled upon my problem,so here it goes.
So sets say,i want to take the third column `$3` of every other line `2nd,4th,6th etc` of input file(i know how to do that) and then print the result at the exactly same position in an output file.
I mean,`$3` of `2nd` line of input,to `$3` of `2nd` line of output and goes on.

I want this,using awk from bash.

Comment: Please post what you have tried.

Comment: I havent tried anything. for the input i did
awk -F " " 'NR%2==0 {print $3}' input.txt , and got the result i wanted. But i have no idea how to code for the output.sorry.

Comment: @markos89, Please post sample input and output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how to do it with  `awk`

```
awk 'FNR==NR {a[NR]=$3;next} FNR%2==0 {$3=a[FNR]}1' firstfile secondfile
```

This will take data from `firstfile` and update `secondfile` using column `$3` and every second line.
Data is replaced in the same position.

```
cat firstfile
1 one green
2 two red
3 three blue
4 four orange
5 five yellow
6 six brown
```

```
cat secondfile
1 one jan
2 two feb
3 three mars
4 four april
5 five jun
6 six juli
```

Running `awk` command:

```
1 one jan
2 two red
3 three mars
4 four orange
5 five jun
6 six brown
```

Too store data back to `secondfile`

```
awk 'FNR==NR {a[NR]=$3;next} FNR%2==0 {$3=a[FNR]}1' firstfile secondfile > tmp && mv tmp secondfile
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Jotne. And if you could please explain to me what does that "1" mean after the '}'. thank you very much.

Comment: The `1` is a command and it will do the default action (print the line), so `1` = `1 {print}` = `1 {print $0}`

Answer (score 1):

It seems you can't explain what you want very well, so I'll guess and maybe you can say what is wrong and it will get solved by process of elimination...

Given an input file called `file`, like this:

```
Line 0,field2,field3,90
Line 1,field2,field3,80
Line 2,field2,field3,82
Line 3,field2,field3,21 
Line 4,field2,field3,85
```

The following awk will print every other line's field3 in the same place as it found it, but without the other stuff around it:

```
awk -F, 'NR%2{print ",,"$3"\n,,";}' file
```

Output:

```
,,field3
,,
,,field3
,,
,,field3
,,
```